# Dockerized .NET 5 Application - System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I have a .NET 5.0 application (using the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker` SDK) that has `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` as its only dependency.

Building and running it locally works fine (Windows x64), but running it dockerized does not work.

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env

WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY ProjectName/*.csproj ./ProjectName/
COPY ProjectName.Test/*.csproj ./ProjectName.Test/

RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./

RUN dotnet publish -c Debug -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "SolutionName.dll" ]
```

Running it produces the following error:

```
container-name_1  | Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
container-name_1  | File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
container-name_1  |    at ProjectName.Program.CreateHostBuilder(String[] args)
container-name_1  |    at ProjectName.Program.Main(String[] args) in /app/ProjectName/Program.cs:line 18
container-name_container-name_1 exited with code 139
```

A quick `ls -lisa` in the `/app` directory of the container confirms the dll is there at least:

```
container-name_1  | 245918   40 -rwxr--r-- 1 root root   37440 Nov 10  2018 Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
```

I have tried explicitly including this dependency in my project, but that produces the same error.
I have also tried downgrading the version of `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` to 3.1.12, but that produces the same error for the same dll but with version 3.1.12.

Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to the `ProjectName.Test` project. Deleting that project fixed the error.